# Test item or test item group start from commandline in TestExecute

Tags: command-line-arguments, testcomplete

### Is it possible to start subgroup of tests from TestExecute command line?

I want to be able to start Emulators or SemiReal subgroup(with folder icons on image) or Emulators or SemiReal test.
I tried different combinations from description: http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/54705/

Here is the last result but still not working:

```
"%PROGRAM_FILES%\SmartBear\TestExecute 10\Bin\TestExecute.exe"
"C:\TestProject\LraTestProjectSuite.pjs" 
/r /p:EpicIteration /projectitem:SemiReal /e
```

Result is:

```
The project item 'SemiReal' was not found in the project 'EpicIteration'.
```

### Test project structure looks like this:

[image: Test project structure]

### What is the right way to start different subgroups of tests from commandline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to run a specific *test item* from the command line. The */projectitem* parameter you are trying to use for this runs a project item (e.g. Network Suite job or specific keyword test), but not a test item.

You can find a solution that will allow you to run individual test items in [this article](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/54655/) on the SmartBear web site.

Comment: Thanks, but it definately must be native functionality for TestComplete and TestExecute command lines. As I see it from support forum it's in backlog scince 2012 or so. Can it somehow be included?
This custom js file still need to be changed to have an ability to pass all parameters and custom parameters. And for group start http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/54654/ it even harder.

Comment: You can contact SmartBear (http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete) and tell them about this functionality you need. I think that your request will be counted somehow.